# Text input value is returning undefined without any error

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input, text

I want to make alert message show the data of the form I input.But the text element's data doesn't work correctly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">



function showUserData(){
category = document.getElementById("category").value;

regicon = "";
var obj=document.getElementsByName("register");
for(idx in obj){
    if(obj[idx].checked){
        regicon += obj[idx].value;
    }
}

title = document.getElementById("title").value;//here is the problem
author = document.getElementById("author").value;
email = document.getElementById("email").value;
content = document.getElementById("content").value;
password = document.getElementById("password").value;
coverdate = document.getElementById("coverdate").value;
contentimage = document.getElementById("contentimage").value;//
time_result = new Date();//기사등록일은 date()

window.alert("카테고리: "+category + "\n"
        + "등록상태: " + regicon + "\n"
        + "제목: " + title + "\n"
        + "이메일: " + email + "\n"
        + "기자: " + author + "\n"
        + "내용: " + content + "\n"
        + "취재일: " + coverdate + "\n"
        + "기사등록일: " + time_result + "\n");
}
</script>
```

When I run the code, the alert show 'undefined' at the title value.
I thought that the title value doesn't initialized so I tried

```
title = "";
```

It was not the solution.How can I make the function run correctly

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please post your html container too?

Comment: Kindly post your html. It is helpful for the community to answer your queries quickly

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a `title`variable? It seems to me you forgot to put "var" or "const" before the title variable.

Comment: I learned that value defined without var is global variable.And if I defined as a constant , the variable couln't be assinged by input.Isn't it?

Comment: No, "var" means that you can change the value of your object (is mutable), "const" is immutable, it receives a value and you can't change it the object.
In your case you can use "const" because you are not changing the value of the object.